# input type number restrict length and allow + sign

Tags: html, regex, angular

I am trying to create a box that takes the country code as input.I want to restrict the user to only enter 3 numbers with a + sign in the beginning. I managed to restrict the length to 3 but I'm unbale to type '+' in the input box.I don't know what to do.Please help.Thanks in advance.
What I'm trying is that user can only enter +123 or +345.Any other pattern he can't enter.
Here's what I've done:

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="phnNumber" oninput="this.value=this.value.slice(0,this.maxLength)" maxlength="3">
```

Comment: Do you want add a prefix  '+' before each country code and want to restrict the country code to 3 digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `(onkeypress)` event and handle the '+' symbol. The decimal ASCII code of `+` is 43:

```
<input type="number" 
    [(ngModel)]="phnNumber" oninput="this.value=this.value.slice(0,this.maxLength)" 
    (keypress)="isNumberKey($event)
maxlength="3">
```

TypeScript:

```
isNumberKey(event)
{
      console.log(event.which)
      var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event['keyCode']
      if (charCode != 43 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
          return false;
      return true;
}
```

In addition, by default, `maxLength` is not working for `type="number"`. However, you can use `pattern` property to allow only digits and then set maximum length of your input type by using `maxLength` property:

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    pattern="\d*" 
    maxlength=3
    (keypress)="isNumberKey($event)" 
>
```

[The work example at StackBlitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qfwhe2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**UPDATE:**

To add `+` just in the beginning of the number:

HTML:

```
<input 
[(ngModel)]="test"
type="text" 
pattern="/^\+[0-9]{2}$/" 
maxlength=3
(keypress)="isNumberKey($event)" 
>
```

TypeScript:

```
test:number;

isNumberKey(event)
{
    console.log(event.which)
    var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event['keyCode']
    if (charCode != 43 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
       return false;

    if(this.test && this.test.toString() && this.test.toString().length >0 
        && charCode == 43)      
    return false;

    return true;
```

}

[The work example at StackBlitz where you cannot insert `+` at the last position.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qfwhe2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: I'm unable to enter '+' in the input box.

Comment: In this I can enter + at any position.I only want to add + in the beginning of the number

Comment: I'm still able to enter

Comment: @rock11 I've checked and it works:) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qfwhe2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 2):

I'll say use a select drop for this task but if you want to you can use a regex matching for this.

```
let pattern = /^\+[0-9]{2}$/

pattern.test("099") // false
pattern.text("+99") // true
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this and it seems to be working the way you wanted

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="phnNumber" 
  oninput="
  if(this.value.length==1 && this.value!=='+')
  {
  this.value='+'+this.value;
  } 
  else
  {
  this.value=this.value.slice(0,this.maxLength);
  }" 
  maxlength="4" pattern="[+][0-9]{3}">
```

Comment: This needs to be edited futher, so that it doesn't accept '+' after 1st place. Currently, It accepts '+' in all places

Answer (score 0):

Firstly - the reason you cant type "+" is because this is a type="number" field - but more importantly - you do not need to type the "+" at all - you can simply present that as part of the input.

You can have a span with the "+" and position it absolutely so that it appears that it is in the input, but is not actually in it. This means that you don't need the slice as you have it.

Note you will also need to give padding to the input so that the actual numbers don't clash. Also -  you will need the input to be wrapped in a div that has position: relative to allow the absolute placement of the indicator.

I have also added a value to this input to demonstrate it - since I didn't have the angular  to add to your example.

```css
.form-group {
  position: relative;
}

.form-group input {
  padding-left: 20px;
  }
  
.indicator { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px; 
  left: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="phnNumber" maxlength="3" value="123">
<span class="indicator">+</span>
</div>
```